# Rails Active Record table associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My question involves a few different active records

```
class Respondent < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :phone_numbers, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :email_addresses, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :phone_number, :foreign_key=> "primary_phone_id"
belongs_to :email_address, :foreign_key=> "primary_email_id"
end

class User < Respondent
end

class EmailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :respondent
has_one :respondent
end
```

The schema for these tables are

```
create_table "email_addresses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.integer  "respondent_id"
end

create_table "respondents", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.integer  "primary_email_id"
  t.integer  "primary_phone_id"
  t.string   "type"
end
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the respondents, and therefore users, capable of having multiple email address but only one primary. For this reason the email record and respondents record link to one another. All of the email address are stored in the email_address record and reference the respondent, and the respondent record has an id to only one email.

In the UserController the following code fails

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @primary_email = EmailAddress.new(params[:primary_email])
    User.transaction do
      @user.primary_email = @primary_email  <=Undefined Method primary_email=
      @user.save!
      @primary_email.save!
      redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user
    end
end
```

First, is this even possible what I am doing?
How can I modify the code to make this controller code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need Respondent to have as associated primary email:

```
has_one :primary_email, :class_name => "EmailAddress"
```

Comment: is this in addition to ..?

   belongs_to :email_address, :foreign_key=> "primary_email_id"

Comment: This does get rid of the error and the email is saved in the EmailAddress record with the right foreign key. However the primary_email_id in Respondent is still null.. any idea?